# Apex oracle is it possible to use a column value in sql query for interactive report?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm learning by myself to use apex and i wonder if there is posibility to use in interactive reports sql query to count from other that with id = *column_1 value* ?

[image: 1]

As u can see in picture.

My actual query:

`

```
select 
    LIB_KSIAZKA.KSIAZKAID as "Id Książki",
    LIB_KSIAZKA.TYTUL as "Tytuł",
    LIB_KSIAZKA.IMIE as "Imię autora",
    LIB_KSIAZKA.NAZWISKO as "Nazwisko autora",
    LIB_KSIAZKA.GATUNEK as "Gatunek",
    LIB_KSIAZKA.OCENA as "Ocena" ,
    (SELECT Count (e.egzemplarzid) 
    from lib_egzemplarz e INNER JOIN lib_ksiazka k ON e.ksiazkaid=k.ksiazkaid
    WHERE e.status='DOSTĘPNA' AND e.ksiazkaid= :P3_ID ) as "Liczba dostępnych egzemplarzy"
 from LIB_KSIAZKA LIB_KSIAZKA;
```

`
As u can see how it should count to the same id of the column1 same row value is.
[in count k.ksiazkaid = 1,2,3,...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/devG5.png)

I tried to set a specific id of column1 but not sure how or even its possible to put it in query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what result you expect, but - to me it looks as if you have to get rid of inner join in a subquery and **correlate** it to a table in the *main* query. Also, it is unclear whether `where` condition(s) in subquery should actually be moved out.

As of table alias: its purpose is to make query easier to read. Using alias which is just the same as table name (`from LIB_KSIAZKA LIB_KSIAZKA`) doesn't help at all.

I'd suggest something like this:

```
select 
    a.ksiazkaid as "id książki",
    a.tytul     as "tytuł",
    a.imie      as "imię autora",
    a.nazwisko  as "nazwisko autora",
    a.gatunek   as "gatunek",
    a.ocena     as "ocena" ,
    --
    (select count (e.egzemplarzid) 
     from lib_egzemplarz e 
     where e.ksiazkaid = a.ksiazkaid  --> correlate subquery to "main" table
       and e.status = 'DOSTĘPNA' 
       and e.ksiazkaid = :P3_ID       --> should that be moved out ...
    ) as "liczba dostępnych egzemplarzy"
 from lib_ksiazka a
 -- where a.ksiazkaid = :P3_ID        --> ... down here?
```